# Difference between "requires" and "when" side conditions

Tags: kframework

For instance if I have some rule `rule <k> foo bar => baz </k> <barList> bars </barList>` and I only want to heat the rule when `bar` is in my list `bars` I believe I would add either `requires bar in bars` or `when bar in bars`. I've been using `when` as my go-to without issue but reading the K manual pending documentation it seems like `requires` may be preferred for this. Both seem to mean "only heat this rule if this condition is met" so I'm unclear on what the difference between `requires` and `when` is as well as in which circumstances to use which. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`when` and `requires` are synonyms, but `when` is considered *deprecated*, so use `requires` instead.